# How to simply read binary data sheets which contains string column in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to (write, read)  a number of tabular data sheets (in, from) a binary file, data are of `Integer`, `Float64` and `ASCIIString` types, I write them without difficulty, I `lpad` `ASCIIString` to make ASCIIString columns of the same length. now I am facing reading operation, I want to read each table of data by a single call to `read` function e.g.:

```
read(myfile,Tuple{[UInt16;[Float64 for i=1:10];UInt8]...}, dim) # => works
```

> EDIT-> I do not use the above line of code in my real solution because
>   I found that
>   `sizeof(Tuple{Float64,Int32})!=sizeof(Float64)+sizeof(Int32)`

but how to include `ASCIIString` fields in in my `Tuple` type?
check this simplified example:

```
file=open("./testfile.txt","w");
ts1="5char";
ts2="7 chars";
write(file,ts1,ts2);
close(file);
file=open("./testfile.txt","r");
data=read(file,typeof(ts1)); # => Errror
close(file);
```

Julia is right because `typeof(ts1)==ASCIIString` and `ASCIIString` is a variable length array, so Julia don't know how many bytes must be read.
What kind of type I must replace there? Is there a type that represents `ConstantLangthString<length>` or `Bytes<length>` , `Chars<length>`? any better solution exists?

EDIT

I should add more complete sample code that includes my latest progress, my latest solution is to read some part of data into a buffer (one row or more), allocate memory for one row of data then `reinterpret` bytes and copy result value from buffer into an out location:

```
#convert array of bits and copy them to out
function reinterpretarray!{ty}(out::Vector{ty}, buffer::Vector{UInt8}, pos::Int)
  count=length(out)
  out[1:count]=reinterpret(ty,buffer[pos:count*sizeof(ty)+pos-1])
  return count*sizeof(ty)+pos
end
file=open("./testfile.binary","w");
#generate test data 
infloat=ones(20);
instr=b"MyData";
inint=Int32[12];
#write tuple 
write(file,([infloat...],instr,inint)...);
close(file);

file=open("./testfile.binary","r");
#read data into a buffer
buffer=readbytes(file,sizeof(infloat)+sizeof(instr)+sizeof(inint));
close(file);
#allocate memory
outfloat=zeros(20)
outstr=b"123456"
outint=Int32[1]
outdata=(outfloat,outstr,outint)
#copy and convert
pos=1
for elm in outdata
  pos=reinterpretarray!(elm, buffer, pos)
end
assert(outdata==(infloat,instr,inint))
```

But my experiments in `C` language tell me that there must be a better, more convenient and faster solution exists, I would like to do it using `C` style `pointers` and `references`, I don't like to copy data from one location to another one.

Thanks

Comment: in your simplified example, `data=ASCIIString(readbytes(file, length(ts1)))` will put out `5char`, but it seems this won't work in your original use case.

Comment: yes, I tried to use `readbytes` in place of `read` but the actual data are of `Vector{mytype}` and mytype are a `Tuple` of different types (all immutables) Ints,Floatings and Char[ConstLength] and I don't know how to do the convertion part. But I am sure that there is a way to convert the pointer of already read `Bytes` to that `Vactor{mytype}` because lines of data are of the same size.

Comment: If I understood you property, the typeof data is  `Array{Tuple{UInt16, Array{Float64,1}, UInt8, ASCIIString},1}` and the content is something like this `(0x0001,[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],0x01,"first")`?  how do you write this into a binary file with a single `write` call?

Comment: I actually write it element by element, `for i in arrayoftuple; write(file,i); end`

Comment: I already have found the lost datatype, I think the variable length type is bitstype, e.g. I can create a new custom bitstype of my desired size like this: `bitstype 8*5 Char5` then read every 5 char field using my Char5 type. but facing another problems, 1-how to convert it to an `ASCIIString` 2-`sizeof(Tuple{Float64,Char5})!=sizeof(Float64)+sizeof(Char5)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array{UInt8}` as an alternative type for `ASCIIString`, which is the type for underlying data.

```
ts1="5chars"
print(ts1.data) #Array{UInt8}
someotherarray=ts1.data[:] #copies as new array
someotherstring=ASCIIString(somotherarray)
assert(someotherstring == ts1)
```

Do mind that I'm reading `UInt8` in a x86_64 system, which might not be your case. You should use `Array{eltype(ts1.data)}` for safety reasons.

Comment: but reading an Array{UInt8} from stream lead you to the same problem of an ASCIIString because size is Unknown. I think the correct type is `bitstype`. but facing new problems, as I already commented above.

Comment: felipe perhaps just misunderstood you @RezaAfzalan, you'd better use a more concrete example rather than that misleading "simplified" example ;)

Comment: Yes, I did... I thought his problem was getting to `read` into `ASCIIString`. Maybe I should erase this? I kept it as it is related, but I know now it's not the answer